# How do I abstract a Formik Field component into a generic sharable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to abstract out the formik  component into a seperate file so taht I can reuse it in different forms and am running into an error (see below) when I break out the  component into a seperate file and import it into the form. Using the  component, or passign in a custom component works fine, but importing it throws an error. Any help would be appreciated. -Chris

I have tried multiple approaches (my code reflects what works and what doesn't). I have dug through the docs and googled quite a bit with no good examples of abstracting the  component into a seperate file.

```
// Test-form.tsx
import React from "react";
import { FormikTextField, CustomComponent } from "@cleaved/formik";
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage, Formik, FormikActions } from "formik";

type TestFormProps = {
  address: string;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
};

export const TestForm = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ address: "", name: "Chris Campbell", phone: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values: TestFormProps, actions: FormikActions<TestFormProps>) => {
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {({ touched, errors, isSubmitting }) => (
          <Form>
            {/* 1 works */}
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
              <Field
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="name"
                className={`form-control ${touched.name && errors.name ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
              />
              <ErrorMessage component="div" name="name" className="invalid-feedback" />
            </div>

            {/* 2 works */}
            <Field
              label="Phone: "
              name="phone"
              placeholder="enter phone number"
              type="text"
              component={CustomComponent}
            />

            {/* 3 doesn't work */}
            <FormikTextField label="address: " name="address" placeholder="enter address" type="text" />

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              {isSubmitting ? "Please wait..." : "Submit"}
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
// formik-textbox.sx
import React from "react";
import { Field, FieldProps } from "formik";

// 2 works
export type CustomComponentProps = {
  label?: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  type: "text" | "password";
};

export const CustomComponent = ({
  label,
  name,
  placeholder,
  type,
  form: { touched, errors }, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
  ...props
}: any) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input type={type} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} />
    {touched[name] && errors[name] && <div className="error">{errors[name]}</div>}
  </div>
);

// 3 doesn't work
export type FormikTextFieldProps = {
  label?: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  type: "text" | "password";
};

export const FormikTextField: React.FC<FormikTextFieldProps> = ({ label, name, placeholder, type }) => (
  <Field name={name}>
    {({ field, form: { touched, errors } }: FieldProps) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{label}</label>
          <input type={type} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} />
          {touched[name] && errors[name] && <div className="error">{errors[name]}</div>}
        </div>
      );
    }}
  </Field>
);
```

```
The error message I'm receiving when importing the <Field /> component (#3) is below:

Uncaught TypeError: this.props.formik.registerField is not a function
    at FieldInner.componentDidMount (formik.esm.js:811)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:17334)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:18736)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:18948)
    at react-dom.development.js:20418
    at Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:255)
    at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:20417)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20346)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20254)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20228)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:20097)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19911)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:20572)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:20600)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:20657)
    at ReactRoot.dll_244e94d4223562f55cdd.../../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:20953)
    at react-dom.development.js:21090
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:20459)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:21086)
    at Object.hydrate (react-dom.development.js:21148)
    at renderReactElement (index.js:31)
    at _callee4$ (index.js:35)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:271)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:27)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:34
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (_export.js:36)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:23
    at _doRender (index.js:35)
    at doRender (index.js:31)
    at _callee2$ (index.js:23)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:271)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:27)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:34
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (_export.js:36)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:23
    at _render (index.js:23)
    at render (index.js:20)
    at _callee$ (index.js:20)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
```

Comment: `touched[name] && errors[name]` you're passing 'address' as name, so either touched or errors is undefined. The stack trace tells you the problem and right where to look, not sure what more we can add to that.

Comment: Sorry, the real error I was getting is: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.formik.registerField is not a function.

I updated my stacktrace.

Comment: You're using all functional components, where is `this` coming from?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not referencing 'this' anywhere in my code. I think is has to do with how Formik registers it's Field component. The first 2 implementations work as expected. The 3rd doesn't for some reason. I'm really not sure though.